# INSERT missing records from template table through SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following set of tables used to manage a paper documents based procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `data` varchar(256),
 `type` varchar(3)
);
```

`TableA` holds the relevant procedure data (for the business logic). The `type` field identify the type of 'procedure' I'm managing.

```
CREATE TABLE Templates (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type` varchar(3),
 `id_doc_type` int NOT NULL,
);
```

`Templates` list all doc types needed to fullfill a specific type of procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE CheckList (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `id_doc_type` int NOT NULL,
 `id_tableA` int NOT NULL,
 `filled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0'
);
```

`CheckList` should contains a set of records with types of documents to be received for each record of `TableA`, `filled` field is used by user to confirm the reception of the specified document type.

```
CREATE TABLE DocTypes (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `doc_type` varchar(24)
);
```

`DocTypes` describe verbosely the type of document.

Hope table and field names helps to find their scope.

The typical content of such tables is the following:

```
TableA:
------------------------------
id   |   data   |    type
------------------------------
0    | data0    |     M
1    | data1    |     M
2    | data2    |     S
3    | data3    |     M
4    | data4    |     S
------------------------------

Templates:
------------------------------
id   |   type   | id_doc_type
------------------------------
0    | M        |     0
1    | M        |     1
2    | M        |     2
3    | S        |     0
4    | S        |     1
------------------------------

CheckList:
----------------------------------------
id   |id_doc_type|  id_tableA  | filled
----------------------------------------
0    | 0         |     0       |  1
1    | 1         |     0       |  1
2    | 2         |     0       |  1
3    | 0         |     2       |  0
4    | 1         |     2       |  0
5    | 0         |     1       |  0
6    | 1         |     1       |  1
----------------------------------------

DocTypes:
------------------------------
id   | doc_type
------------------------------
0    | doc_type 0
1    | doc_type 1
2    | doc_type 2
------------------------------
```

I wrote several stored procedures to manage such tables but for some reason due to the previous data management model the `CheckList` table has some 'holes' just like the one depicted above:

As you can see only records 0, 1 (referring to `id` value) of `TableA` have the full set of doc type references in `CheckList`, record 2 has only a partial set of doc types references and records 3, 4 are fully missing.

I need to write an SQL procedure to fillup everything keeping existing data and avoiding to create dupes.

As I stated I already wrote procedures. Among that I wrote one to fillup an empty `CheckList` section (i.e. it create the set of records for a fully unreferenced record of `TableA`, just like records 3 and 4) but I cannot figure out how to partially recover situations like record 2.

As suggested in comments this is what `CheckList` table should looks like after the procedure being completed:

```
CheckList:
-----------------------------------------
id   |id_doc_type|  id_tableA  | filled
-----------------------------------------
0    | 0         |     0       |  1
1    | 1         |     0       |  1
2    | 2         |     0       |  1
3    | 0         |     2       |  0
4    | 1         |     2       |  0
5    | 0         |     1       |  0
6    | 1         |     1       |  1
7    | 2         |     1       |  0
8    | 0         |     3       |  0
9    | 1         |     3       |  0
10   | 2         |     3       |  0
11   | 0         |     4       |  0
12   | 1         |     4       |  0
-----------------------------------------
```

This's a portion of the fillup stored procedure I wrote modified to fit my needs (but not working):

```
INSERT INTO CheckList (id_doc_type, id_tableA)
    SELECT id_doc_type, @id_tableA
    FROM Templates 
    WHERE 
        type = @type
        AND NOT (id_doc_type IN (
            SELECT id_doc_type 
            FROM CheckList 
            WHERE    
                id_tableA = @id_tableA));
```

Of course `@id_tableA` and `@type` were parameters of my procedure while in this case they cannot be used (or maybe they can but we need an external procedure iterating over `tableA` records).

I'm using MySQL 5.7 as a backend of ASP.NET web application.

Comment: Just make it clear... The result you need

Comment: correct... I will add the expeting data.

Comment: The way I would do it would be to have the unique index in place to eliminate dupes (including a unique composite if that is the case). So maybe just one index. then do an `insert ignore` with a select (from a single table or a join). The `ignore` would care less about the data that was already there which would have triggered an error

Comment: @Drew please code. I got what you meant about the UNIQUE key but I'm not sure to understand how you would got the rest.

Comment: If you create the sqlfiddle [Ha just talking about that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this

```
insert into checklist (id_doc_type, id_tablea, filled)
  select t.id_doc_type as id_doc_type, a.id as id_tablea, 0 as filled
    from tablea a
    join templates t on a.type = t.type
    left join checklist c on a.id = c.id_tablea and t.id_doc_type = c.id_doc_type
    where c.id is null;
```